# SaccadeAngular velocity Matlab

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, theoretical-neuroscience, mathematical-psychology

I have the data for a monkey's eye position in a cartesian plane synced to the time. I can convert the numbers into polar form however I'm not too sure how to find the angular velocity at that point. My main struggle is implementing the math formulas into Matlab.
Thankyou

Comment: angular velocity is change in angle divided by change in time

Comment: It is a question for stack exchange